# LibMailcore2 Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, mailcore2

Does anyone have instructions howto use Libmailcore2 with Visual Studio 2015?

Do I have to rebuild the library? I can only find Studio 2013 and especially Objective C examples.

When trying to build the mailcore project, there are lots of errors, for example:

```
c:\vstudio\mailcore\src\core\smtp\mcsmtpsession.cpp(754): error C3861: 'mailesmtp_send_quit_no_disconnect': identifier not found
```

Although, this function exists in mailsmtp_helper.h:

```
LIBETPAN_EXPORT
int mailesmtp_send_quit(mailsmtp * session,
                      const char * from,
                      int return_full,
                      const char * envid,
                      clist * addresses,
                      const char * message, size_t size);

LIBETPAN_EXPORT
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you linked the library?
First way is to add it in the project properties in the linker group.
Second way is to use `#pragma comment(lib, "...")`. Replace `...` with the real name of the library (lib).

Comment: If you still have this problem try using the `g++` version or something else.

Comment: When adding the `pragma` or the name of the lib to through the options don't forget to add `.lib` as file extension.

Comment: Good luck with your project :)